# Teamcity Gives error while running Nunit runner : Has no Text Fixture

Tags: nunit, teamcity

I am trying to run some unit tests in teamcity build configuration. I am using NUnit.ConsoleRunner.3.6.1 . However It says "Has no TestFixture". But when I tried to run it in command prompt using same runner it completed successfuly. What are the possible reasons ?

Answer (score 0):

Really, more info is needed to judge what your problem is. However, most errors of that type indicate that the nunit framework has not been deployed with the test assembly that uses it.